# Prevent UITableViewCell highlighting when image in content view is touched

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have added a `UIImageView` to the right side of the content view of my `UITableViewCell`.

I am trying to prevent the cell from being highlighted while the user is touching the `UIImageView` (because an attached gesture recognizer performs some other functionality).

I have thought about implementing `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` and returning `NO`, but I am unsure how to easily determine if the image is being touched when this method is called. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can we see your implementation?  Did you set  `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: Yes, user interaction is enabled. There is no problem actually interacting with the UIImageView – it's just that the cell may still be highlighted while doing so.

Comment: Should the cell be highlighted/selected if the user taps the cell but not the image on the right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    // Add tap gesture recogniser to cell's image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;

    cell.theImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.theImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return cell;
}
```

The important parts are to make sure the image view has `userInteractionEnabled = YES` and the gesture recogniser has `cancelsTouchesInView = YES`.

This will cause the `tapped` method to fire if the image view is tapped, but the cell will not be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add a `UIButton` with type custom.Will have the tap button action.Will not affect the cell highlight

Prevent highlight of tablecell

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

or

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```